# Text parsing of log file in GO

Tags: go

Go newbie here!

I am trying to put together a Go program that will parse a log file and return specific information on lines matched.

To give an example of what I am trying to achieve I would start with a log file that looks like this:

```
2019-09-30T04:17:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:18:02 - REQUEST-C
2019-09-30T04:19:02 - REQUEST-B
2019-09-30T04:20:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:21:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:22:02 - REQUEST-B
```

From here I would want to extract all "REQUEST-A" and either print the time the request occurred to the terminal or to a file.

I have tried using os.Open and scanner and I can use scanner.Text to log that it has found occurrence of my string, like so:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    request := 0
    f, err := os.Open("request.log")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("There has been an error!: ", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        if strings.Contains(scanner.Text(), "REQUEST-A") {
            request = request + 1
        }

        if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        }
        fmt.Println(request)
    }
}
```

But I am unsure of how to take this to use it to retrieve the information I am after.
Normally I would use Bash for this but I thought I would branch out and see if I could use Go.
Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: unless you need something you can't achieve with bash, prefer bash to an home made go implementation. You will get better performance, less bugs.

Comment: @mh-cbon: The question is about and tagged as "a Go program." Your suggestion is not an answer; it's [Taco Bell Programming](http://widgetsandshit.com/teddziuba/2010/10/taco-bell-programming.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go, we try to be efficient. Don't do things unneccessarily.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    lines, requestA := 0, 0
    f, err := os.Open("request.log")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("There has been an error!: ", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines++
        // filter request a
        line := scanner.Bytes()
        if len(line) <= 30 || line[30] != 'A' {
            continue
        }
        if !bytes.Equal(line[22:], []byte("REQUEST-A")) {
            continue
        }
        requestA++
        request := string(line)

        // handle request a
        fmt.Println(request)
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(lines, requestA)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run request.go

2019-09-30T04:17:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:20:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:21:02 - REQUEST-A
6 3

$ cat request.log
2019-09-30T04:17:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:18:02 - REQUEST-C
2019-09-30T04:19:02 - REQUEST-B
2019-09-30T04:20:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:21:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:22:02 - REQUEST-B
```

---

To emphasize the importance of efficiency (logs can be very large), let's run a benchmark against [Markus W Mahlberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1296707/markus-w-mahlberg)'s solution: https://play.golang.org/p/R2D_BeiJvx9.

```
$ go test log_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkPeterSO-4   21285     56953 ns/op    4128 B/op      2 allocs/op
BenchmarkMarkusM-4     649   1817868 ns/op   84747 B/op   2390 allocs/op
```

`log_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

var requestLog = `
2019-09-30T04:17:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:18:02 - REQUEST-C
2019-09-30T04:19:02 - REQUEST-B
2019-09-30T04:20:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:21:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:22:02 - REQUEST-B
`

var benchLog = strings.Repeat(requestLog[1:], 256)

func BenchmarkPeterSO(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(benchLog))
        for scanner.Scan() {
            // filter request a
            line := scanner.Bytes()
            if len(line) <= 30 || line[30] != 'A' {
                continue
            }
            if !bytes.Equal(line[22:], []byte("REQUEST-A")) {
                continue
            }
            request := string(line)
            // handle request a
            _ = request
        }
        if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkMarkusM(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        var re *regexp.Regexp = regexp.MustCompile(`^(\S*) - REQUEST-A$`)
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(benchLog))
        var res []string
        for scanner.Scan() {
            if res = re.FindStringSubmatch(scanner.Text()); len(res) > 0 {
                _ = res[1]
            }
        }
        if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why no regex? Expensive once, enough performance later, much less code.

Comment: regexp is slow in comparison to byte comparison and positions manipulation

Comment: @mh-cbon Well, I benchmarked both approaches (can push the code, if you want), and either way we are talking of a one digit µs/op. Not sure wether this is worth it. In a text parsing library? May be. In a Go implementation of an awk script? May be not.

Comment: it depends your level of requirement, your input, the time you are ok to compute this. But still i see a 5 times difference between the two approaches. It can make a difference. (`BenchmarkRe-4        100000      12350 ns/op     4496 B/op       13 allocs/op` / `BenchmarkByte-4     1000000       2142 ns/op     4304 B/op        7 allocs/op`)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: Your [Go solution](https://play.golang.org/p/R2D_BeiJvx9)  is inefficient. I've added a benchmark.

Comment: Interestingly, I get rather different values in my benchmarks. See https://github.com/mwmahlberg/textparsebench

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to print the time field for log entries with the value field "REQUEST-A".

```
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    if len(line) < 19 {
        continue
    }
    if line[19:] == " - REQUEST-A" {
        fmt.Println(line[:19])
    }
}
```

[Run it on the Go play ground!](https://play.golang.org/p/48ZPIcooqul)

To write to a file, redirect stdout to a file.

The code above assumes that everything after the timestamp is "- REQUEST-A".  Use the following if "- REQUEST-A" is a prefix to other data:

```
const lenTimestamp = 19
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    if len(line) < lenTimestamp {
        continue
    }
    if strings.HasPrefix(line[lenTimestamp:], " - REQUEST-A") {
        fmt.Println(line[:lenTimestamp])
    }
}
```

[Run this version on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WhjfbKfESiX).

Answer (score 0):

No need for a Go program if you are on a Linux or Mac:

```sh
$ echo "2019-09-30T04:17:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:18:02 - REQUEST-C
2019-09-30T04:19:02 - REQUEST-B
2019-09-30T04:20:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:21:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:22:02 - REQUEST-B" | awk '/REQUEST-A/{print $1}' | tee request.log
2019-09-30T04:17:02
2019-09-30T04:20:02
2019-09-30T04:21:02
```

However, if you really want to implement this in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

const input = `
2019-09-30T04:17:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:18:02 - REQUEST-C
2019-09-30T04:19:02 - REQUEST-B
2019-09-30T04:20:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:21:02 - REQUEST-A
2019-09-30T04:22:02 - REQUEST-B
`

var scanner = bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(input))

// Here comes the magic: We create an anonymous group containing all
// non-whitespace characters up to the first blank. Since it is
// a group, we can easily extract it later down the road.
var re *regexp.Regexp = regexp.MustCompile(`^(\S*) - REQUEST-A$`)

func main() {
    var res []string
    for scanner.Scan() {
        // We use re.FindStringSubmatch here, as it actually kills two
        // birds with one stone: We check wether it is REQUEST-A
        // and the anonymous group of the regexp contains what we are looking for.
        if res = re.FindStringSubmatch(scanner.Text()); len(res) > 0 {
            fmt.Println(res[1])
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[Run on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/R2D_BeiJvx9)**</kbd>

Comment: The question is about and tagged as "a Go program." Your first solution is not an answer; it's [Taco Bell Programming](http://widgetsandshit.com/teddziuba/2010/10/taco-bell-programming.html). Your second solution in Go appears to be inefficient; see my answer.

Comment: @peterSO LoC-wise... As said, I benchmarked both solutions, and we are not talking orders of magnitude, though significant. Your solution is a bit more than 4 times faster: 1.4µs vs 5.8µs per op on average. It is safe to assume that I/O operations will more likely be the bottleneck, so I went for less LoC as being efficient. And I find it important to think outside the box, according to the saying „If all you have is a hammer, everything starts to look like a nail.“: The first solution provides the requested result with zero implementation effort.

Comment: I would be interested to see your benchmark code. Add it to your answer.

Comment: @peterSO Still interested? Sorry, I just saw your request only now.